# Aframe componentchanged not working in v1

Tags: javascript, dom-events, aframe, webvr

I am building a multiplayer experince with SocketIO and AFrame. This snipped worked perfectly fine in Aframe 0.5, however whan I switched to v1, it suddently stopped working. The "componentchanged" listener simply never fires. "Found Myself" is always printed so its not like myself is null.

```js
socket.on('connect',function(){

  console.log('connected to server');
  let myself=document.getElementById('user-cam')
  if(myself!=null){
    console.log(name)
    console.log("FOUND MYSELF")
    const player={name:name,translation:[0,0,0],rotation:[0,0,0]};
    socket.emit('player connect',player);
    isConnected=true;
    myself.addEventListener('componentchanged', function (evt) {
      console.log("Component Changed");
      console.log(evt.detail.newData);
      if(evt.detail.name==='position'){

        player.translation=[evt.detail.newData.x,evt.detail.newData.y,evt.detail.newData.z];
        socket.emit("PlayerMove",player);
      }
      if (evt.detail.name==='rotation'){
        player.rotation= [evt.detail.newData.x,evt.detail.newData.y,evt.detail.newData.z];
        socket.emit("PlayerRotate",player);
      }
    });
  }
  else{
    console.log("NOT FOUND");
  }

});
```

Comment: I tested this code for every version 0.5 and after, it works perfectly for 0.5 an 0.6, there's an error for 0.7 and 0.8 (To be expected cause evt.detail only contains the name of the attribute that was changed starting at 0.7). Starting 0.9 it just never fires ("Component Changed" Doesn't log)

Answer (score 0):

'componentchanged' no longer works for position/rotation/scale attributes if they are changed using el.object3D.position/rotation/scale in AFRAME 0.9 or later. To track changes in them you need to use AFRAME.registercomponent, and check element.object3D.position/rotation/scale inside tick or tock functions. More info [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4531)